# Beautiful Soap Scraping Content

Tags: web-scraping, beautifulsoup

[image: target screenshot]

Is there a way to get the number (13) at the very end?

I tried below code:

```
url='https://mgm.gov.tr/?il=Ankara'

req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})

web_page = urlopen(req).read()

soup = BeautifulSoup(web_page, 'html.parser')

mydivs = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "tahminMax"})[0]

mydivs
```

and received following output:

```
<div class="tahminMax"><span class="deger" ng-bind="gunlukTahmin[0].enYuksekGun1 | kaliteKontrol"></span><span class="derece">°C</span></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Values are retrieved dynamically from another xhr call you can find in the network tab. You can extract them as follows:

```
import requests

headers = {'Origin': 'https://mgm.gov.tr'}
r = requests.get('https://servis.mgm.gov.tr/web/tahminler/saatlik?istno=17130', headers=headers).json()
d = {i['tarih']:i['maksimumRuzgarHizi'] for i in r[0]['tahmin']}
print(d)
```

Answer (score 1):

The site is handled by `JS` events which loaded after site loading. Below you can achieve your goal using `selenium`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

url = 'https://mgm.gov.tr/?il=Ankara'
sada = browser.get(url)

source = browser.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')


for tag in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "tahminMax"}):
    for span in tag.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'deger ng-binding'}):
        print(span.text)
browser.close()
```

[image]

also here's `BeautifulSoup` doing the task but the output of `13` will not be loaded.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r = requests.get('https://mgm.gov.tr/?il=Ankara')
time.sleep(3)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')


for tag in soup.findAll("div", attrs={"class": "tahminMax"}):
    for span in tag.findAll('span', attrs={'class': 'deger', 'ng-bind': True}):
      print(span.text)
```